# C# MySql force blocking mode

Tags: c#, mysql

I have the following code:

```
static void InsertRes(string Data)
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO results (gamenum,result) " + Data;
            query += ";";
            //open connection
            if (OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                //Execute command
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //close connection
                CloseConnection();
            }
        }
```

I know it's not the best practices but I generate data within my application, how can I force this function to block until the query has been successfully executed upon the mysql database?

Answer (score 0):

It will do that automatically.

`cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` will return **after** the insertion is finished.

That is standard programming behaviour. Doing multiple task simultaniously is where it gets tricky. Doing one thing after the other is just normal. Your program will continue to the next line only when the execution if the preivious line is finished.

Comment: There is a chance of it throwing an exception for some reason and not completing though which seems to be the only logical explaination for why I do not get that insert sometimes?

Comment: If you have an exception you should notice it, right? Hard to tell without more info why it does not work sometimes.